# CMake - appending CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS from the command line

Tags: c++, cmake

I would like to add some `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` from the command line to the flags defined in CMakeLists.txt, for example:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wall" ..
```

It will work only when flags are appended to the list in the CMakeLists.txt, for example:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
```

In the following case:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
```

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` passed from the command line wil be overwritten.

Is there any way to prevent overwritting flags defined in the command line without modyfing CMakeLists.txt ?

Comment: "Is there any way to prevent overwritting flags defined in the command line without modyfing CMakeLists.txt?" - No, there is no such way. If a project decides to hardcode `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` value, you (as a poject's user) cannot prevent the project to do that. You could to fill bugreport for the code which hardcodes `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`: it does not only discard custom flags from the user, but it discards flags which CMake automatically detects for the compiler.

Comment: Hardcoding `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is ~always a bug. Report it to upstream.